# Print_r() response from an API call

Tags: php, arrays, api, object

So I am trying to store a value of the response but I don't know how. After I `print_r()` the array I get the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
[user_id] => id number
[access_token] => access token code
[token_type] => BEARER
)
```

My question is how do I for example set a variable to the access_token?
Like this:

```
$access_token = $array['access_token'] ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an array, it's an object (see the first line of the `print_r()` output). To access an object property, you use `->`, not `[]`:

```
$access_token = $array->access_token;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your object to an array like this

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($your_object), true);
```